# Updating UILabel realtime with UIDatePicker

Tags: objective-c, uidatepicker

I have everything set up. I just need to know how to get the UILabel to update as the user goes through the UIDatePicker.

```
NSDate *myDate =dateView.date;
dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; 
//NSDate *date = [NSDate date]; 
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM d y"]; 
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:myDate]; 
NSLog(@"New Date is = %@",dateString);
self.firstDateDisplayed.text = [self.dateFormatter stringFromDate:self.dateView.date];  

}
```

(This is all in an IBAction)
If you need anymore code just let me know. Many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You would put something like this in your `viewDidLoad` method:

```
[dateView addTarget:self action:@selector(whateverTheMethodsCalled:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

And then the actual target method.

```
-(IBAction)whateverTheMethodsCalled:(id)sender{
    //NSDate *myDate =dateView.date;
    dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; 
    //NSDate *date = [NSDate date]; 
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM d y"]; 
    //NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:myDate]; 
    //NSLog(@"New Date is = %@",dateString);
    firstDateDisplayed.text = [self.dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateView.date];  
}
```

Or in IB you can connect the datepicker's `valueChanged` event to your `IBAction` method.

`UIDatePicker` like all `UIControl`s has a paradigm called `UIControlEvent..` the one your interested in here is `valueChanged`; It's similar to how button events fire your `IBAction` methods for `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`. All that `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` does is say that when that control event happens you want a call.

Comment: So I need to create a (void) valueChanged?

Comment: Glad you got it working. I hope the edit still clears some things up.